# EntityFramework: Remove m2m association given only primary keys. How?

Tags: entity-framework

I've two entities a and b and an m2m association between them. Entities a and b are loaded in my DbContext, while the m2m associaiton is not. Now, in my program I know the primary keys of a and b and I need to remove the m2m association.

Of course, I could -reload a from the database and include its m2m association. However, this requires an additional round trip to the data base to get the entities from the database.

I could also first detach a from the DbContext, then add b to its BSet, then attach a again and then call remove something like:

```
context.Entry(a).State = EntityState.Detached;
a.Bset.Add(b)
context.Set(typeof(A)).Attach(a);
a.BSet.Remove(b)
```

However, by detaching a from its context and then attaching it, I loose the changes that have been made to a. Consequently, calling SaveChanges() may not persist all changes of a to the database.

My question is: how can I remove the m2m association between a and b without an additional round trip to the database and without loosing any changes made to a or b?

[edit: What I'm looking for is a method a.BSet.Attach that would enable me to attach an existing m2m association between a en b]

I'm using the latest version of Entity Framework and I'm using DbContext.

Any help is welcome.

PS. this is a repost of http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/adodotnetentityframework/thread/5edea208-24cc-497b-8592-9cb025d558e4/

Thanks in advance,

Merijn

Answer (score 0):

I was in the same problem a few days ago and the solution I came up is:

```
context.Entry(a).State = EntityState.Detached;
a.BSet.Add(b);
context.Entry(a).State = EntityState.Modified;
a.BSet.Remove(b);
```

with that code you should be removing the m2m association and preserving all the changes to the database.

EDIT:
I just realized that we have made almost the same code, just reattach your entity changing its state to 'Modified'.

Comment: Hi, Thanks your help. Unfortunately this does work for properties, but not for associations. In particular, new M2M relations for a disappear when detaching a. They will not come back when setting a's enttiy state to EntityState.Modified later on.